# headers include and cyclic dependency

Tags: c++, header, dependencies

I'm wondering why the code bellow is not working.
In b.cpp, class B uses class A, but it fails because the declaration of the class A is not found.
However, a.hpp is included just before. Why the #include "a.hpp" is not working here?

Thanks for any help!

```
//===============================================
//file: a.hpp
//===============================================
#ifndef _A_HPP
#define _A_HPP

#include "b.hpp"

class A{
    public:
        A();
        // others methods using B here
};

#endif


//===============================================
//file: a.cpp
//===============================================
#include "a.hpp"

A::A(){}


//===============================================
//file: b.hpp
//===============================================
#ifndef _B_HPP
#define _B_HPP

#include "a.hpp"

class B{
    public:
        B(A a);
};

#endif
//===============================================
//file: b.cpp
//===============================================
#include "b.hpp"

B::B(A a){}



SHELL$ g++ -c a.cpp
In file included from a.hpp:7,
                 from a.cpp:4:
b.hpp:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘a’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[Forward declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)** to break such circular dependency.
However, note that once you forward declare a type, that type becomes an **Incomplete Type** for the compiler and there are restrictions on how you can use the Incomplete type

Answer (score 1):

This won't work.  In you header files you should only include references or pointers to the other class.  Then you can forward declare A or B, e.g.:

```
//===============================================
//file: b.hpp
//===============================================
#ifndef _B_HPP
#define _B_HPP

class A;

class B{
    public:
        B(A& a);
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
#include "b.hpp"
```

from `a.h` and only have a forward declaration - assuming you use pointers to `B` in `A`:

```
//A.hpp

class B; //forward declaration

class A{
    public:
        A();
        // others methods using B here
};
```

**Also:** Macro names starting with underscore `_` are reserved by the standard and should not be used. Replace `_B_HPP` with simply `B_HPP`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a cyclic `#include` like that?  If you just need for the compiler to know a class exists (so it can be a parameter et cetera), just forward declare it like this:

```
class A;
```

Don't cyclically include files.  Even with the guards, they'll both only be included once, sure, but then you're still going to run into a mention of `A` before the compiler gets to its definition, or a mention of `B` before the compiler gets to its definition.

Comment: I was thinking an #include was better, to not duplicate code and make maintenace easy. But ok, the duplicated code is just "class A;" and it should not be much longer in a real long source code...

Answer (score 0):

When b.hpp includes a.hpp, `_A_HPP` is already defined, so the precompiler ignore the content of the file, so in the line `B(A a)`, the compiler doesn't know about A.

if you really need these includes, try move the `#include "b.hpp"` to the end of `a.hpp` (or declare `class A;` in the head of `b.hpp`).

Comment: I was thinking everything was in a big file, that finally contains: a.cpp + a.hpp + b.hpp

Answer (score 0):

In A.hpp, do not include B.hpp or inline A implementations that call B methods.

Use `class B;` in A.hpp (a forward declaration) if you need to refer to `B&` or `B*`.

Instead, put those A implementations that call B methods in A.cpp and include B.hpp in A.cpp.